# PromQL - How to filter metric entries based on first occurence?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql, kubernetes-jobs

The `kube_job_status_failed` is a constant metric (either 1 or 0) for which we have entries that already appeared before a selected time range.

**How do we filter those jobs that reported their first metrics in the given time range?**

Or ask differently:

**How do we filter the metric entries for those jobs that were created and finished in the given time range?**

---

### Further explanation

As far as I understand `kube_job_status_failed`, as long as the kubernetes job isn't deleted, the metric will stay 1 and doesn't change until the job is removed.

Failed job `test-sync` was executed 3 hours ago, filtering for `kube_job_status_failed{job_name="test-sync"} > 0`  within the last 2 days makes this visible as the line for that job starts only 12:00:

[image: test-sync]

Failed job `test-sync-old` was executed 14.01.2024 at 03:00, filtering for `kube_job_status_failed{job_name="test-sync-old"} > 0`  within the last 2 days, the job line starts at the beginning of the selected range:

[image: test-sync-old]

As there are many reported job metrics with `kube_job_status_failed` of jobs that started before our selected time range, I only want to select those metrics which first reported value started within our time range, excluding those metrics where the line is there at the beginning of our selected range.

So in this example only `test-sync` should show up.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to do?

Comment: @markalex I gave a more detailed explanation of what I want, I hope the explanation is sufficient, maybe `kube_job_status_failed` is configured wrong, but at least in our setup it is a constant metric that doesn't change over time and also is reported for each timepoint.